# How to break into next iteration in while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I have a segment of while loop:

```
kw=[]
while len(kw)<count:
    for keyword in keywords:
        for ekw in ekw_embeddings:
            if np.inner(keyword,ekw)>threshold:
                kw.append(keyword)
```

Here after the last if condition how to goto next iteration of while loop without checking next for loop?

Comment: what would be the purpose of for loop then?

Comment: You seem to have made a large change to your question. What happened to the `while` loop?

Comment: Sorry I messed it up after editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One technique you can use is to encapsulate the `for` loops inside a function:

**Update after question modified:**

```py
def f(kw, keywords, ekw_embeddings):
    for keyword in keywords:
        for ekw in ekw_embeddings:
            if np.inner(keyword, ekw) > threshold:
                kw.append(keyword)
                return

kw = []
while condition:
    f(kw, keywords, ekw_embeddings)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a stop condition:

```
lst=[]; stop = False
while stop == False:
    for num in nums:
        for num2 in nums2:
            if condition:
               lst.append(num)
               stop = True
               break
        if stop == True:
            break
```

And btw don't call a list (or anything in general) using python object names (so a dict would not be called `dict` or `list` etc...)

In case you can use a function:

```
def func(nums,nums2):
    lst=[]
    while condition:
        for num in nums:
            for num2 in nums2:
                if condition:
                   lst.append(num)
                   return lst

lst = func(nums,nums2)
```

Comment: That only breaks the lowest for-loop, not up to the while-loop.

Comment: Is it just me or "for num2 " looks unnecessary in the code?

Comment: The `stop = True` still doesn't break out of either `for` loops.